# Saving JSON to member field?

Tags: add-on, solspace-user

Has anyone saved JSON in a custom member field? I have a big array I'd like to tie to member registration. I'm using the User module to register. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your concerns or what isn't working for you? JSON is just plain text and therefor could be saved in a textarea. I have never used User (as I save my members as channel entries) but I don't see why it wouldn't work. The real question is what you plan to do with that JSON and where you wish to display that field.

Answer (score 1):

That was exactly what I needed to do, just didn't think about it at the end of the day. Building the JS object onClick of the button, then filling a textarea prior to submit. Thanks for the point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What we did was wrote a, extension and handle the hook that updated the entry and added it there.

This was for BrilliantRetail and we needed to add JSON to a field for each product when being added to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this, and although my situation was pretty unique, hopefully it still helps.

In my situation, I needed to add lots of data from a template, and I wanted to use `Freemember` to easily save it as a custom field. Here were the steps:

1. Created a simple "dummy" html `form` with all the necessary inputs, independent of Freemember, with no form action or onClick event (just a `form` tag, inputs, and a submit button).
2. Created a separate (hidden) `form` with one hidden field that's set up via Freemember's `{exp:freemember:update_profile ...}` tag. This field is set to submit to my custom member field, and has an empty `value` attribute. This is what actually gets submitted.
3. When the dummy form is submitted, I used jQuery's amazing `.serializeArray()` method to collect all the dummy form data into a nice js object, and then a really simple [json-jquery](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) plugin to turn that into a proper `JSON` string.
4. Once I have my json string from all the form fields, I use it to populate my Freemember form's hidden `input` tag, and trigger it's submission.

Keep in mind, for most cases this is a sloppy approach. Building a proper extension / module and implementing solid validation is likely the way to go. For someone like me who's way quicker in JS than EE Extension Development, this was a nice workaround. At the very least, hopefully this approach brings other methods to light =).

Best of luck!